# the spectral radius in a unital Banach algebra

Tags: functional-analysis

If x,y are commuting elements in a unital Banach algebra,how to prove that

$r(x+y)\leq r(x)+r(y)$and $r(xy)\leq r(x)r(y)$,where r is the spectral radius

Comment: What do you know about the spectral radius? Can you use the formula $\lim \|x^n\|^{1/n}$?

Comment: If you're allowed to use Gelfand, here is a reference: http://books.google.fr/books?id=zDos2FzHO7MC&pg=PA20&lpg=PA20&dq=spectral+radius+r(x%2By%2B+%3C+r(x)+%2B+r(y)&source=bl&ots=t5p-ai4yUl&sig=lSxyW3GQ0URPD9aMIOlokBm2geI&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=Qt0sUZm6KILy0wHC1YCICw&ved=0CC0Q6AEwADgK#v=onepage&q=spectral%20radius%20r(x%2By%2B%20%3C%20r(x)%20%2B%20r(y)&f=false

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define $B$ to be the Banach subalgebra of $A$ generated by $\{1, x, y\}$. First you have to show that $r_A(a)=r_B(a)$ for all $a\in B$, where $r_A(a)$ denotes the spectral radius of $a$ in $A$ and similarly for $r_B(a)$.

Now you can use the Gelfand theory for the commutative Banach algebra $B$. In other words, use the fact that $r_B(a)=\|\hat{a}\|_{\sup}$, where $\hat{a}$ is the image of $a$ under the Gelfand transform; $a\mapsto \hat{a}$, $\hat{a}(\omega):=\omega(a)$ for all $\omega \in \Omega(B)$.